# How to import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser in java?

Tags: java, ant

I'm planning to analyze the java code of Apache Ant with XRay (an unkown plugin for eclipse to analyze projects). I have the project in eclipse, but I can't import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser, in the class JavaClassHelper. I have similar problems for other classes

I don't know how to import the followings:

```
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantValue;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Field;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
```

I have also the following problem:

In the package org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.jdepend, in the class JDependTask, I have the followings errors:

```
    setFilter =
        jdepend.textui.JDepend.class.getDeclaredMethod("setFilter",
                                                       new Class[] {packageFilter});
```

"jdepend cannot be resolved to a type"

```
public int executeInVM(CommandlineJava commandline) throws BuildException {
    jdepend.textui.JDepend jdepend;

    if ("xml".equals(format)) {
        jdepend = new jdepend.xmlui.JDepend();
    } else {
        jdepend = new jdepend.textui.JDepend();
    }
```

Every time there's "jdpend" or "jdepend.something", I get the error: "jdepend cannot be resolved to a type"

Moreover, I can't resolve the following problem, in the package org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh, in the class SSHBase:

```
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
            "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
```

the error is: "The method setConfig(Properties) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your project builder, you need to add a dependency for BCEL, so that Eclipse can pull down that dependency and your code can compile. The latest version of BCEL is referenced here, including the steps to include it for the most popular builders; maven, gradle, etc.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bcel/bcel/5.2

Comment: Do you know also how to resolve: "jdepend cannot be resolved to a type"?

Comment: That probably should be a separate question, but it looks like the same issue really, a missing dependency...check out http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdepend/jdepend/2.9.1

Comment: On a second glance, maybe not...I'd remove that from this question and start fresh, its not the same type of missing dependency declaration actually...I think

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I have solved the problem with your link, installing jdepend!

Comment: Could you resolve also the last problem I have submitted (session.setConfig(String, String)), please?

Comment: You're passing in a pair of Strings as params where a Property is expected. Properties are typical read from file containing a number of key value pairs like your original api key...look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html to understand more but I can't say for certain in this case what properties you need and where you need to put them,sorry!